# RavenDB get ID of newly stored document

Tags: c#, ravendb

I started playing around with RavenDB (which really looks great so far). However I'm stuck trying the following.

I store a new document like so

```
Product p = new Product() { Title = "My Fancy Product" };
RavenSession.Store(p);
```

Now I would like to get the Id of the newly stored document. Who can this be done? Just to access `p.Id` after the store doesn't seem to work ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your `Id` property type an integer or a string?

Comment: It is of type integer

Comment: It should be a string.

Comment: Why should it be a string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Id` property of the `Product` class must be of type `string` instead of integer.

Then you will be able to retrieve the autogenerated id after the operation:

```
Product p = new Product() { Title = "My Fancy Product" };
RavenSession.Store(p);
string id = p.Id;
```

More information can be found in the [`documentation`](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/basic-operations/saving-new-document) (`Document IDs` section):

> In the example above we had a string Id property for BlogPost, and
>   left it blank. It is this property that will be used as the "primary
>   key" for this document. Note how RavenDB generated an ID for us,
>   "BlogPosts/1", based on the default convention which we will discuss
>   in a second.
>
> If there is no Id property on a document, RavenDB will still generate
>   a unique ID, but it will be retrievable only by calling
>   session.Advanced.GetDocumentId(object). In other words, having an Id
>   property is entirely optional, so you can explicitly define such a
>   property only when you need this information to be more accessible.

Comment: Thats great.. but it returns `documentName/id` - That might be a spanner in the works but that is how it is I suppose. +1

Comment: @ppumkin How hard is a string split? Must be a delicate works if that looks like a spanner.

Comment: Sure, I suppose NoSQL is a paradigm shift and all the relational database conventions are oddities here. I would have thought that string split would be OK, or better it would be just better stop trying to use NoSQL like a relational DB. I know the error of my ways now, 3 years later :D